# SearchQuery's modifybefore and modifyafter property will cause query error

Tags: 2011, tom.net, search

We are trying to use SearchQuery to get a list of components inside our C# TBB. Below is the code:

```
SearchQuery sq = new SearchQuery(session);
sq.IsPublished = true;
sq.ItemTypes.Add(ItemType.Component);
//API Limitation, only support 1 keywords
sq.UsedKeywords.Add(keyword);
DateTime? after = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100);
DateTime? before = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
sq.ModifiedAfter = after;
sq.ModifiedBefore = before;
sq.SearchIn = pub;
IEnumerable<IdentifiableObject> result = sq.GetResults();
```

But we get the following errors:

```
Unable to process the Search Request. Invalid search query:  

RepositoryId:tcm\:0\-3\-1 OR RepositoryId:tcm\:0\-4\-1 
OR RepositoryId:tcm\:0\-5\-1 OR RepositoryId:tcm\:0\-6\-1 
OR RepositoryId:tcm\:0\-7\-1 OR RepositoryId:tcm\:0\-21\-1) 
AND (ItemType:16) 
AND ModificationDate:[2013-03-05T21:23:01Z TO 2013-06-15T21:23:01Z] 
AND (CatchAllXml:"href tcm\\:*\-57814\-1024")
```

If we remove the Modify time related code it will works fine: 
    `*sq.ModifiedAfter = after;`
    `sq.ModifiedBefore = before;*`

I notice inside the error message, the date-related script seems to be not the same as the others, it wasn't wrapped by parentheses.

What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing rendering via a CM API, i.e. at publish time, does it make sense to query for items that may be modified in the future (that is 'before AddDays(2)')?  This is a statement that can never be true because NOW is the latest modified date that is possible when querying during static rendering/publishing.

I suggest either setting both, 'after' and 'before', to be <=NOW or setting only 'after' leaving 'before' at its default of NOW.

Comment: We tried all situation, like only Modified before, only Modified after, add both, search it between 4/2013 to 5/3013. It doesn't care what you input. If you use one of these criteria, this error will popup.